# MSMQ and WebSphere MQ message integration

Tags: c#, msmq, biztalk, ibm-mq

Does someone know how to integrate MSMQ to an IBM WebSphere MQ? I guess one can always use BizTalk 2009 (Biztalk host integration server)but that seems to be quite an overkill just to be able to exchange messages between MSMQ and WMQ. Please give me some advice! Someone must have done this before!

If it helps your recommendation the WMQ is running in a main frame environment, and one under zLinux (SLES 11).

Br.
Ausgar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a MSMQ-MQSeries Bridge available through Host Integration server

Search for "Using the MSMQ-MQSeries Bridge" under HIS 2009, cause I can't post links....

Comment: Hi,

since no one else seams to have any more input I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a .NET application to pick up your MSMQ messages and deliver them to the WebSphere MQ queue manager over a client connection. It's not ideal but lower cost than the BizTalk solution.

Comment: Hi,

This is true, one could build an application that handles this. But are there any "out of the box" products made for this (except from BizTalk)?

Comment: Microsoft Host Integration Server used to provide this function I think, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Sadly, it seems that the MQ / MSMQ bridge is to be deprecated http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/02/04/future-of-the-msmq-mqseries-bridge.aspx. Writing a custom bridge would be a quick and dirty (and cheap) solution.